# UPI intent in node js?

Tags: node.js, android-intent, payment-gateway, rect, upi

Is it possible to integrate UPI intent flow in a web application made by using react and express ?

I went through a lot of documentation and was not able to find anything related. I now intend is for phones but if we want to integrate in a web application then what should be done ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.